# Bundle.main.url return nil when reading the file contents in swift5

Tags: swift, swift5

I would like to create a generic helpers function to read the file contexts. However, when I use Bundle.main.url the `file` is always `nil`. But if I create a classs and use `Bundle(for: xx).url(...)?.path` then, no problem for me to get the contents. anyone may know what is the issue?

```
class ABC {

    func _getContentsByFileName(fileName: String, withExtension fileExt: String) -> String {
        guard let filePath = Bundle(for: ABC.self).url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: fileExt)?.path, // no problem to get filePath
            let content = try? String(contentsOfFile: filePath) else {
            print("Failed to read")
            return ""
        }
        return content
    }

    func readFile(fileName: String, withExtension fileExt: String) -> String {
        return Self._getContentsFromClass(fileName: "createSession", withExtension: "json")
    }
}

func getContentsByFileName(fileName: String, withExtension fileExt: String) -> String {
    file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: fileExt, subdirectory: "Data") // file is nil
    return String(decoding: file, as: UTF8.self)
}


let instance = ABC()
print(instance.readFile("fileName", "txt") )

print(getContentsByFileName(fileName: "fileName", withExtension: "txt"))
```

Comment: Did you try without the `subdirectory` parameter? `file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: fileExt)`

Comment: yes still does not work

Comment: Is the ABC class part of a framework, library, or pod? Or is it a class in your main project target? A class in a framework/library will have its own bundle so the file won't be in the main bundle.

Comment: the class is in my main project target and I have no problem to use it. but I just can't use "Bundle.main.url". if `getContentsByFileName` is under file belongs to multiple target that how can I use `Bundle.main.ur`?

Comment: You could try extending the `Bundle` class, add the `getContentsByFileName` function in the extension.

Comment: Can you post the actual code or a minimal reproducible example? What you have posted here contains a number of errors and won't compile. For example, either you shouldn't have `Self._get...` or `_getContentsByFileName` should have been declared static or as a class function. Also `file` is never declared.